# React onClick issue while using CSS Active Pseudo Class

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React js code with below code functionalities. Input component has a "x" font awesome icon used to clear the data inside input field. The onClick functionality is not working on icon inside input form. But CSS active class is working fine. Code as given below

SandBox Link available at: [sandbox-test-code](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactclickissue-5wuxw)

Input component as

```
const Input = () => {

function xClick(){
console.log("Hello");
}

return (    
<div className="inp_form">
  <input 
    className="inp"
    type="text"
    placeholder=" "
    autoComplete="nope"        
  />
  <i className="fas fa-times" onClick={xClick}></i>
  <label className="inp_lbl">First Name</label>
</div> );
}
```

At the same time, my CSS stylesheet contains below code

```
@import url('https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css');
.inp_form{
position: relative;
margin: 1rem 2.5rem;
width: 30rem;    
height: 4.5rem;          
}
.inp{
position: absolute;
padding-right: 3rem;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;    
}
.inp_form > i{
position: absolute; 
top:25%;
font-size: 2rem;   
right:3%;
padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
transition: transform ease-in-out 50ms;
}
.inp_form > i:hover{  
color:red;   
}
.inp_form > i:active{
transform: scale(0.98%);
}
```

While pressing the button, console is not working. **CSS active Pseudo is over writing button onClick function.** Can anyone please help me get an answer for the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the full component code?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't seem to have any issue. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pond-iy353?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Neeraj! 
Actually I was not getting it worked for <i>, for better understanding I wrote it as <button>. 

The <i> class is been used inside a input class. I will update the question for more clarity

Comment: Code updated with real issue I am facing, it's a Input Component which has a label and "X" button to clear the input data

Comment: Shouldn't `onClick={xClick}` be placed on `input` element instead of `i` ? Plus in the css, the `inp_form` classname is missing a dot `.` i.e. it should be `.inp-form`. Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am using <i> with font awesome "X" icon. Clicking on it will clear all input elements.

missing dot in class name is a typo. Let me correct it in question

Comment: I am posting question for the first time. Will take care of such issues going forward. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: That should work as you expected, the console is giving "hello" as expected.

Comment: It's not giving output! I even tried to add the same to sandbox,  there to it's not giving results.

Comment: Code kept in SandD Box Linked added to question
at:- https://codesandbox.io/s/reactclickissue-5wuxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` event is a combo of `mousedown` and `mouseup` on the same element.
Since you scale the element out of existence (*out of the mouse pointer more precise*) you do not get the `mouseup` triggered on that element and so the `click` is never happening.

You could use `onMouseDown` event ([*demo*](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-mountain-nrw6t?file=/src/App.js))

```
<i className="fas fa-times" onMouseDown={xClick}></i>
```

---

or you could use a wrapper element ([*demo*](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-frost-fpji0))

```
<span className="icon" onClick={xClick}>
  <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
</span>
```

and

```
.inp_form > .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  right: 3%;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
}
.inp_form > .icon i {
  transition: transform ease-in-out 50ms;
}
.inp_form > .icon:hover i {
  color: red;
}
.inp_form > .icon:active i {
  transform: scale(0.98%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele Petrioli! Your answer solved my issue!